# How can I get Facebook and Google contacts to sync in 4.2?

Tags: contacts, facebook, 4.2-jelly-bean

In the People app (i.e. Google Contacts), the "Accounts" area has an option for adding Facebook contacts, which I've checked. In `Settings->Accounts->Faceboo`k, I've checked "Sync Contacts," yet it doesn't look like my Facebook contacts are being synced. I have the Facebook app installed and logged in. Is there something I'm doing wrong? This is on a Nexus 4 running Jelly Bean (4.2.1).

Ideally, I'd like to import/sync Facebook contacts into Google Contacts without using third-party apps, and without installing an address book replacement.

Comment: I don't think this is possible without a third party app or a custom rom. You aren't doing anything wrong, it is just Google and Facebook not playing nice together anymore, apparently. (Most people recommend the app [HaxSync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mots.haxsync&hl=en) as a workaround by the way, I haven't tried it yet though)

Comment: >That feature was removed in the 4.x versions of Android. That can't be entirely correct, as the syncing still works just fine on my Galaxy S3 running 4.1.2, though it doesn't work at all on my new Nexus 7 running 4.3. Moreover, if it's been "removed," why does the People app -- not just the top-level os Settings for Facebook, but the actual contacts app itself -- still include syncing Facebook contacts as a specific option in its own settings?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That feature was removed in the 4.x versions of Android.  I use [UberSync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ro.weednet.contactssync) for my contact syncing and it works great.  Haven't had any problems with it and it also has a setting to import high res contact photos.  I would recommend that.  Set it up once and forget about it.

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed that my FB contacts were no longer in my Motorola DROID RAZR MAXX, and not Joined to the original "phone number only" Contact listings for many Friends.

I followed the steps listed in the top answer, and even though the UI on my phone says the FB Sync is off, Tapping "People > Bottom-Left Menu button > Accounts > Facebook", and then Tapping the "Contacts (Touch to sync now : Sync is OFF)" did successfully sync my FB contacts.

I then had to go to my Contact list, find the original People Contact, Tap the Contact > Tap Bottom-Left Menu button > Tap Edit > Tap Bottom-Left Menu button > Tap Join -- then find the FB Contact, complete and save the Join.

All is now good

DROID RAZR MAXX
Android version: 4.1.2

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a [TamperMonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en) / [GreaseMonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) script to accomplish this, which works by encoding the contact details on a friend's "about" page into a google-goggles-scannable QR code.  It's not as convenient as the (missing) ability to do a bulk export/import or sync, but seems to be the best option under the circumstances.

The TamperMonkey script is [here on GitHub](https://github.com/ifreecarve/facebook-contact-qr-generator)

Answer (score 0):

If you have many friends or followers on Facebook & Twitter & a big group on Google Plus, then you can synchronize all those contacts with their email-ID & phone numbers to your mobile phone’s contacts.

http://www.androidwala.com/how-to-get-facebook-contacts-on-android-phone/[image]